# Can not start basic react-native AwesomeProject

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I followed the steps for create basic react-native AwesomeProject. And I tried both ways for create it. Still I have same issue. Can somebody help me?[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT5LX.png)

Answer (score 0):

FYI
You just need to use `react-native start` command in terminal (your project directory) while running the app and tap to reload in simulator, hope your app will run if there is no error in code.

Thanks